# how to loop over grouped items, python pandas GroupBy.get_group

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I would like to create new data frames from the group Variance report that I use everyday. But some days some of the groups do not have variances. But the code I wrote needs all the groups to have variances every day, loop over the the group if they do not have any variances that day.

```
df = df.groupby('Store')
dt_string = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
Tday =pd.to_datetime('today',format='%Y-%m-%d').normalize()
Today_ = str(Tday)
extension_ = '.xlsx'
print(Today_)
#df_columns =list(df.columns)

df_NSC = df.get_group('Nicolway')
df_HVM = df.get_group('Highveld')
df_CGM = df.get_group('Retail Centre')   
df_MM = df.get_group('Middleburg ')
df_SM = df.get_group('Secunda Mall')
df_GSM = df.get_group('Greenstone ')
df_PM = df.get_group('Phola Mall ')
df_KM = df.get_group('Kwagga Mall ')
df_HM = df.get_group('Highland Mews')
df_JM = df.get_group('Jubilee Mall')
```

Comment: Maybe there is someone who understands what you mean,  but personally I struggle to understand what you mean. Can you provide a minimal working example as well as the expected output? In other words: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, except from "iterating over a dataframe"?

Comment: Hi I want to write these on different sheets on a excel workbook but if for instance the group nicolway does not have any data for today then I want it to skip that work book and not write anything or just say data not available, hope this is a bit clearer

Comment: Use if ... esle for all sheets. If the df is empty just make an empty df.